# How to add more fields to bbPress registration form

Tags: bbpress

How can I add one or more extra fields to the registration form in bbpress 2.0.2?

I want to add a textarea where prospective users can write their reason for joining the forum.

Comment: any help on this? maybe someone has worked with bbPress, its a bit frustrating how little support there is at the mom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the WordPress login and bbPress logins are the same. So you can just find code to tweak the WordPress registration form, or indeed use a plugin, which is very simple:http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/

Answer (score 1):

This is completely untested as I don't use bbPress or have a copy on hand to try out for myself, but [this page](http://bbpress.org/forums/topic/can-i-add-form-fields-to-the-registration-page) seems to have some code that allows you to add new registration fields.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Customize User Profile
*/

add_filter( 'get_profile_info_keys', 'customize_user_profile', 10, 2 );

function customize_user_profile( $fields, $context ) {
    /**
     * Remove undesired fields
     *
     * Commented =   left
     * Uncommented = removed
     */
//  unset( $fields['first_name'] );
//  unset( $fields['last_name'] );
    unset( $fields['user_url'] );
//  unset( $fields['from'] );
    unset( $fields['occ'] );
    unset( $fields['interest'] );

    /**
     * Add new fields
     *
     * Quoting functions.bb-core.php, line 906:
     * meta_key < (required?, Label, hCard property).  Don't use user_{anything} as the name of your meta_key.
     */
    $fields['my_meta_key'] = array(
        false,
        __( 'My meta key' ),
        'text'
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

*Note: Edit is a copy/paste from the linked source.*

Comment: Didn't work for me but I found the solution using this plugin:http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/installation/